# Close popup-menu when it's already shown

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I have a JPopupMenu, that I want to show on a button click and hide when the user clicks on the button a second time (JMenu-like behavior). I have troubles implementing the second part because the second click closes the popup menu automatically. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PopupAction extends AbstractAction {

    private final JPopupMenu popup;

    public PopupAction(String text, JPopupMenu popup) {
        super(text);
        this.popup = popup;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof Component && !popup.isVisible()) {
            Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
            popup.show(c, 0, c.getHeight());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(PopupAction::createTestUI);
    }

    private static void createTestUI() {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test popup");
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.add("Item 1");
        popup.add("Item 2");
        popup.add("Item 3");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JButton(new PopupAction("Items", popup)));
        frm.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.setSize(500, 300);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I've found a solution but it looks fragile for me due to using the method `EventQueue.getCurrentEvent()` (I use it to check from a `PopupMenuListener` whether the curent event is the mouse pressed event on my button). Have somebody a better idea?

Here is my "fragile" solution (probably somebody can use it to find a better idea).

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PopupAction extends AbstractAction {

    private final JPopupMenu popup;

    private boolean ignoreNextAction;

    private final PopupMenuListener pml = new PopupMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            onClose();
        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            onClose();
        }

        private void onClose() {
            AWTEvent e = EventQueue.getCurrentEvent();
            if (e instanceof MouseEvent && ((MouseEvent) e).getComponent() instanceof JButton) {
                MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) e;
                JButton b = (JButton) me.getComponent();
                if (PopupAction.this.equals(b.getAction()) && me.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                    ignoreNextAction = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public PopupAction(String text, JPopupMenu popup) {
        super(text);
        this.popup = popup;
        popup.addPopupMenuListener(pml);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof Component && !ignoreNextAction) {
            Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
            popup.show(c, 0, c.getHeight());
        }
        ignoreNextAction = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(PopupAction::createTestUI);
    }

    private static void createTestUI() {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test popup");
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.add("Item 1");
        popup.add("Item 2");
        popup.add("Item 3");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JButton(new PopupAction("Items", popup)));
        frm.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.setSize(500, 300);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what problem you're facing. "the second click closes popup menu automatically" reads as if this were a problem but don't you want the second click to close the popup if it's visible? Btw, instead of checking `e.getSource() instanceof Component ` etc. in the action listener I'd register it just on the button so you always know it was the button that triggered it.

Comment: @Thomas I also didn't fully understand that part. After testing it, the result is that clicking (anywhere) closes the popup, clicking on the button however, closes and instantly reopens the popup (which is what is to be fixed).

Comment: @Thomas I want to prevent the reopening of popup on second click. First click on my button opens popup, the next one closes it. Of course a click anywhere else also closes the popup.

Comment: I've tried a solution with a mouse listener on my button, but when it's called the popup menu is already closed.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I also just tried that. The issue is, that on the activation of the `mousePressed`, `popup.isVisible()` already returns `false`.

Comment: @maloomeister yes. I've debugged my "fragile" solution and found that another way to solve this problem is to override the method `dispatchEvent` for my button. But it's also bad for me because I need a custom extension for my JButton.

Comment: I've added my "fragile" solution. Probably somebody can use it to find a better idea